# Unexpected label width value

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

i am reading the width of a label at three different times and only one of them is producing the correct output.. code:

```
from tkinter import *

def getwidth(string):
    print(string+str(lbl1.winfo_width()))

root = Tk()

lbl1 = Checkbutton(root, text="test text")
lbl1.grid(row=0,rowspan=2)


print("first "+str(lbl1.winfo_width()))
getwidth("second ")

btn = Button(root, text="GO", command=lambda x="third ": getwidth(x))
btn.grid(row=2)

root.mainloop()
```

How can i read the correct width (69) during the first two outputs without having to rely on the button command? Thanks

current outputs are:

```
first 1
second 1
third 69
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, unfortunately, you can't.  The first two times are done *before* the window is loaded (which causes it to return the default value of `1` since the label isn't drawn yet).  The third time is done *after* the window is loaded (the label is drawn), so it returns the correct number.

You have to remember that, until you call `root.mainloop` and load the window, the widgets are not placed on the screen.  Sure, they exist behind the scenes (otherwise a `NameError` would be thrown), but they are not on the screen and taking up space yet.  Thus, when you try to see how much space they are taking up, you get the default number of `1`.

Comment: ouch, the "i dont think you can" is gone XD just a note, the widgets must exist so you can modify them and grid them and stuff or i would get 'name chk does not exist' but yes i believe you're right. i see no way of doing this :(

Comment: @DCA- Hhm, I think I worded that badly.  By "does not exist", I mean the window isn't loaded and thus the label isn't taking up any space on the screen.  Behind the scenes, yes, the label does exist or otherwise a `NameError` will be thrown.  I meant "exist" as in "placed on the loaded window so that it is visible and taking up screen space".

Comment: saying they don't exist is a bit misleading. They exist, they just haven't been drawn. The size is indeterminate until they've been put on the screen, since the size is affected by pack/place/grid options, the size of the window, etc.